# How to include iframe coding in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

How to include iframe coding in joomla

Answer (score 3):

Joomla has TinyMCE as default Editor. It don't allow iframe tag.

You can enable iframe tag in Editor.

**Go to > Extensions > Plugins > TinyMCE**

Paste `iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder]` 
in **Extended Valid Elements**

Now go back to your editor, open html view and paste your iframe code. It will save it.

Answer (score 0):

`Edit HTML` in the editor and add the `<iframe>` tag there.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to paste an image in a frame, so after i understood that i can't use frames i paste this code, cause i needed scroller.

```
<p style="overflow:scroll;width:700px;"><img style="border: 1px solid #000000;" src="/images/img.png" alt="img"></p>
```

If you need to paste a video from youtube it is better to hide the video under a image (screensho for example) giving the link to video. not iframe nor embed doesn't work in joomla.

hope that help)